# Stream data to Apache Phoenix using flume

Tags: hbase, bigdata, apache-zookeeper, apache-phoenix, mapr

When I am trying to stream data to Phoenix using flume I am getting the following error

```
ERROR client.ZooKeeperSaslClient: Exception while trying to create SASL client
java.security.PrivilegedActionException: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: Failure to initialize security context [Caused by GSSException: Invalid name provided (Mechanism level: KrbException: Cannot locate default realm)]
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:421)
        at org.apache.phoenix.shaded.org.apache.zookeeper.client.ZooKeeperSaslClient.createSaslClient(ZooKeeperSaslClient.java:283)
        at org.apache.phoenix.shaded.org.apache.zookeeper.client.ZooKeeperSaslClient.<init>(ZooKeeperSaslClient.java:131)
        at org.apache.phoenix.shaded.org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.startConnect(ClientCnxn.java:949)
        at org.apache.phoenix.shaded.org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1003)
Caused by: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: Failure to initialize security context [Caused by GSSException: Invalid name provided (Mechanism level: KrbException: Cannot locate default realm)]
        at com.sun.security.sasl.gsskerb.GssKrb5Client.<init>(GssKrb5Client.java:149)
        at com.sun.security.sasl.gsskerb.FactoryImpl.createSaslClient(FactoryImpl.java:63)
        at javax.security.sasl.Sasl.createSaslClient(Sasl.java:372)
        at org.apache.phoenix.shaded.org.apache.zookeeper.client.ZooKeeperSaslClient$1.run(ZooKeeperSaslClient.java:288)
        at org.apache.phoenix.shaded.org.apache.zookeeper.client.ZooKeeperSaslClient$1.run(ZooKeeperSaslClient.java:283)
        ... 6 more
Caused by: GSSException: Invalid name provided (Mechanism level: KrbException: Cannot locate default realm)
        at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5NameElement.getInstance(Krb5NameElement.java:129)
        at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5MechFactory.getNameElement(Krb5MechFactory.java:95)
        at sun.security.jgss.GSSManagerImpl.getNameElement(GSSManagerImpl.java:202)
        at sun.security.jgss.GSSNameImpl.getElement(GSSNameImpl.java:476)
        at sun.security.jgss.GSSNameImpl.init(GSSNameImpl.java:201)
        at sun.security.jgss.GSSNameImpl.<init>(GSSNameImpl.java:170)
        at sun.security.jgss.GSSManagerImpl.createName(GSSManagerImpl.java:137)
        at com.sun.security.sasl.gsskerb.GssKrb5Client.<init>(GssKrb5Client.java:107)
        ... 10 more
```

I am using an unsecured `mapr` cluster, and I didn't configured any Kerberos authentication in my cluster
What could be the issue please help